# How to delete input color picker image?

Tags: reactjs, input, color-picker

I tried to delete color-picker image on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jBRU.png) but i couldn't. Why did this happen although I didn't create an image tag and how can I delete it?
My code is below. Thanks in advance for your helps.

```
<div className={styles.colorPicker}>
      <input
        className={styles.input}
        type="color"
        value={color}
        onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br></br>
      <button className={styles.btn} onClick={changeColor}>
        Change Color
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is added by the ColorPick Eyedropper Chrome extension. Disable the extension.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that! 

Comment: Thank you so much . I could not find out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: If you see a link or something with `src` being `chrome-extension://`, it's most likely added by an extension. The image's `title` also tells you here.